# What is a Twitter Timeline and how do you use it?

Tags: twitter

What is a Twitter timeline, and how does it work? How do you access it? Is this a timeline in  "Moments"?

[image: moments Twitter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply your Twitter home page.

From [Twitter support](https://support.twitter.com/articles/164083):

> When you log in to Twitter, you'll land on your Home timeline.
>
> - Your Home timeline displays a stream of Tweets from accounts you have chosen to follow on Twitter. You may see suggested content powered by a variety of signals. You can reply, Retweet, or like a Tweet from within the timeline.
> - Tweets you are likely to care about most will show up first in your timeline. We choose them based on accounts you interact with most, Tweets you engage with, and much more. You can find instructions for how to turn off this behavior here.
> - You may see a summary of the most interesting Tweets you received since your last visit, labeled as While you were away.
> - You may also see content such as promoted Tweets or Retweets in your timeline.
> - Additionally, when we identify a Tweet, an account to follow, or other content that's popular or relevant, we may add it to your timeline. This means you will sometimes see Tweets from accounts you don't follow. We select each Tweet using a variety of signals, including how popular it is and how people in your network are interacting with it. Our goal is to make your Home timeline even more relevant and interesting.
> - Clicking anywhere on a Tweet in your timeline expands the Tweet, so you can see photos, videos, and other information related to that Tweet.
>
> Where you'll see other timelines:
>
> - Timelines can also consist of collected Tweets from users in lists that you've curated or as search results.
> - When you click on a list, you will see an aggregated stream of Tweets (a timeline) posted by the users included in that list.
> - Similarly, when you perform a search, you'll see a timeline of Tweets that all match your search terms.